# Filter through an array of objects

Tags: javascript

Having an array of objects with this structure[image]
My question is how should a filter it to return, for example, only the objects with meterName = "Bay-3". That hexadecimal header at each object tangles me.

Comment: please post the raw data instead of images, that will be easy for people who are going to answer to copy that data and show a working example

Comment: I put it like that in a different question but I got lots of negative votes because they said the format of the array is not correct.

Comment: You can copy data from console, by right clicking as selecting option store as global variable, which will return a reference, use `copy(referencename)` to copy data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get object key using Object.keys() and then process the data

```
const result = data.filter(datum => {
    const key = Object.keys(datum)[0];
    return datum[key]['meterName'] === 'Bay-3';
})
```